# Read CSV items with column name

Tags: python, csv

When reading a CSV, instead of skipping the first line (header), and reading row items by number:

```
with open('info.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        blah = row[1]
```

is there a built-in way to access row items by making use of the header line? Something like:

```
with open('info.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', useheader=True)
    for row in reader:
        name = row['name']
        blah = row['blah']
```

where `info.csv` has a header line:

> name;blah
> John;Hello2
> Mike;Hello2

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You are looking for [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
with open('info.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        name = row['name']
        blah = row['blah']
```

to quote from the link:

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader but maps the
>   information read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional
>   fieldnames parameter.
>   ...
>   If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of
>   the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instance to get this behaviour.

Example from the docs:

```
>>> with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
Eric Idle
John Cleese
```

The reader generates the dictionary keys from the first row of the csv file automatically.  If the csv file does not contain a header row you can set the keys by passing a list to the `DictReader`:

```
fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is. That's what [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) function does - supplies the rows as an iterable of dicts.